# How to change the default behavior of the ThickBox?

Tags: thickbox

I am using Thickbox in one page,
now as u know, if we click out side the thickbox page [means in the black part],

so i want to remove that behavior, i want to remove that thing....means if the user had click out side of that page in dark part then the page should not be remove-disappear, it should stay in the window..

the only way to close the thickbox page by clicking on that "Close" link,

so is their any way to do this?

thanks in advance,

Nitz.

Comment: just add &modal at the end of url. #TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=pleaseloginagain&modal=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Thickbox.js go to the function  `tb_show`

In this if statement:

```
    if (typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === "undefined") {//if IE 6
        $("body","html").css({height: "100%", width: "100%"});
        $("html").css("overflow","hidden");
        if (document.getElementById("TB_HideSelect") === null) {//iframe to hide select elements in ie6
            $("body").append("<iframe id='TB_HideSelect'></iframe><div id='TB_overlay'></div><div id='TB_window'></div>");
            $("#TB_overlay").click(tb_remove);  //Remove me
        }
    }else{//all others
        if(document.getElementById("TB_overlay") === null){
            $("body").append("<div id='TB_overlay'></div><div id='TB_window'></div>");
            $("#TB_overlay").click(tb_remove); //Remove me
        }
    }
```

You need to comment out both lines that contain `$("#TB_overlay").click(tb_remove);`.  I have added a comment of `//Remove Me` on the lines you should comment out.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but i found another way to do it without changing thickbox source code, after i launch the thickbox window, i do the following:

```
tb_show('', 'website.php?inlineId=hiddenModalContent&amp;TB_iframe=true');
jQuery("#TB_overlay").off('click');
```

This removes the click action, so it becomes like a modal window without losing the titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you :-)

```
$("#TB_overlay").unbind("click",tb_remove);
```